# Hooks: How to get global state (this.state)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

React - 16.8.6
React-dom - 16.8.6
Next.js - 8.1.0

So, I'm in the process of upgrading some legacy code to be Hook compliant, and want to know how to achieve the following using an equivalent hook:

```html
<Mutation mutation={UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION} variables={this.state}>
  <form />
</Mutation
```

where `this.state` is the sum total of all held form data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having to discern a lot from so little information. I assume that you want to use the React hook, like `useState()`, rather that referring to the `this.state` and `setState`.

Assuming you have something like

```
import React from 'react'
class WrappingComponent extends React.Component {
   state = {value1: '', value2: 0}

   render() {
       return (
          <Mutation mutation={UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION} variables={this.state}>
             <form />
          </Mutation>
       )
   }
}
```

You need to

1. Convert the class component to a functional component.
2. Initialize the state and use `useState()` to retrieve state as a local value.
3. `useState()` also returns a setter which takes the place of `this.setState()` for that specific state element.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
function WrappingComponent() {
   const [value1, setValue1] = useState('')
   const [value2, setValue2] = useState(0)

   return (
      <Mutation mutation={UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION} variables={{value1, value2}}>
         <form />
      </Mutation>
   )
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. All that you have mentioned, I am already utilising. I simply wanted to know whether I can grab the entire state and pass it, without having to do { value1, value2 }?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is a completely different question than I spent time answering and has nothing to do with hooks. See "Spread Syntax" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

So, what I was looking for was;

```html
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    value1: '',
    value2: '',
    value3: 0,
    ...
  });

 const handleValueChange = (e) => setState({ ...state, value1: e.target.value });
 ...
 <Mutation mutation={UPDATE_ITEM_MUTATION} variables={state}>
```